# Sort Count in C++. how can I skip a part of the sorting?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

so I had the following sorting example (Count Sort), It's kind of weird actually, but it works, so it's fine :

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int getMx(int* arr,int n)
{
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > max)
        {
            max = arr[i];
        }       
    }
    return max;
}

void CountSort(int* arr, int n) {
    int* output = new int[n];
    int max = getMx(arr, n);
    int* count = new int[max + 1];

    for(int i = 0; i < max + 1; i++) {
        count[i] = 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        count[arr[i]]++;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
        count[i] += count[i - 1];
    }

    for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        output[count[arr[i]] - 1] = arr[i];
        count[arr[i]]--;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = output[i];
    }



    delete[] output;
    delete[] count;
}

int main () {
    int arr[] = { 100, 5, 2, 0, 125 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    CountSort(arr, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So the main idea is just to get rid of the part when I sum the numbers stored in each index on Count[i]. And just get the output after the second cycle.

Example

`int arr = [3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 0]` 
`int count=[1,1,1,1,1,1]`

and from there I should get

`int output= [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

So I couldn't figue this out ((

Comment: Is that a question ??

Comment: And what about sorting [324, 443663, -23] ?

Comment: how to skip 3-rd cycle and go from cycle 2 to the result ?

Comment: What makes you think that this is possible ?

Comment: in my head, if it was python, then I could just do the follow: after int cout = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  for (int i = max; i >= 0 ; i--) {
  if (count[i] != 0) {
   for (int j = 1; j <= count[i]; j++)
   {
                          output.append(i)
   }
  }
 }

Comment: but as we know, there is no append command in c++

Comment: So you say that if you know you have a permutation of 0,1,..,n-1 then you can skip sorting altogether? If yes, I couldn't agree more. Your question is unclear. Please reformulate it clearly, maybe this will help you solve your problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably thinking of something like this:

```
void CountSort(int* arr, int n) {
    int max = getMx(arr, n);
    int* count = new int[max + 1]{};

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        count[arr[i]]++;
    }

    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
        while (count[i]--) {
            arr[k++] = i;
        }
    }

   delete[] count;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TvjErcs89)